# How do I create an Azure function app with array of inputs (scheduled)

Tags: azure, azure-functions, scheduled-tasks

I want to have an Azure function app that triggers on schedule, with 6 different input.
for example, I want to trigger per hour with different inputs.

So function is same code and will run 6 times every hours, each independent run to be executed with only change in function inputs.

Is this a scenario that is supported?
Naïve option is to write 6 scheduler triggered functions that use same inner function, but it feels "redundant".

Comment: What kind of input are we talking about? A function can only have one trigger so how would you pass the input? Where is the input coming from?

Comment: URL to get data from, there are 6 different URLs, each have to be queried hourly then result logged to application insights

Answer (score 2):

I can think of some options:

- Use a single timer triggered azure function that calls the same http triggered azure function accepting a single url, for each url. In this scenario the timer triggered function knows which 6 urls to pass to the http triggered function.
- Use a timer triggered logic app that calls an http triggered function six times, passing a single url to the function. Basically the same as 1) but with a logic app as the initiator.
- Use a timer triggered durable function using the [fan-out pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-overview?tabs=csharp-inproc#fan-in-out) to call the same function in parallel. The benefit of this approach vs the first option is that you know when the parallel function invocations are finished so you can take action upon completion.

Comment: Thanks, that is similar to what I have had in mind.
So I guess no support in another input parameter in timer functions right?

Comment: Correct, though there is the concept of input bindings, which allows you to bind to, for example, a [storage blob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-input?tabs=python-v2%2Cin-process&pivots=programming-language-csharp#example). Not really a parameter but it might come in handy sometime.